# Move Azure DevOps Organization from one subscription to another

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have created an Organization under my current subscription, which was a fault. I have done a lot of configuration and setup so I can't just change subscription and create a new. I have changed the billing correctly, but when I pick my profile I can still see the Organization under the wrong subscription.

Is there any way for me to move it? Or do I just have to recreate it.

It kind of look like this

- my account - > company subscription - > customer organization

But I really want to have

- my account - > customer subscription - > customer organization

Or maybe it is as simple, when to hand over the project, to reassign the customer as owner?

Comment: Does this org back with AAD? If yes, which AAD is backed now, your company's AAD or customers'?

Comment: Both subscriptions is controlled by same AD

Comment: Could you share the screenshots about the view of "org is under the old subscription in My profile"? I'm confuse about this displayed message.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT I will when I get to a computer!

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT I have written to our support partner about it. I will keep this updated with info as soon as I get answers.

Answer (score 3):

If they belong to the same Azure AD Tenant, changing the billing subscription should do it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/change-azure-subscription. In Azure portal, do a Ctrl+F5 as sometimes you get the cached information.

Comment: I think the billing changes. It is just if I log in to dev.azure.com and click my profile the organization is still under the old subscription even though the billing points to the new.